# Why did the HelloWorld codes using cocoa's library fail to build?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

The codes are like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        // insert code here...

        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    }
    NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    [alert setMessageText:@"Hi there."];
    [alert runModal];


    return 0;
}
```

What I want is: when called from command line, this program pops up an alert box, when I close the alertbox. The program exits.

But when building, it complains like this:

```
Ld /Users/hanfei/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KeyCatcher-hijnrqhwiafuxtdjmdubtsijyhwh/Build/Products/Debug/KeyCatcher normal x86_64
    cd /Users/hanfei/Desktop/KeyCatcher
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.9
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -L/Users/hanfei/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KeyCatcher-hijnrqhwiafuxtdjmdubtsijyhwh/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/hanfei/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KeyCatcher-hijnrqhwiafuxtdjmdubtsijyhwh/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/hanfei/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KeyCatcher-hijnrqhwiafuxtdjmdubtsijyhwh/Build/Intermediates/KeyCatcher.build/Debug/KeyCatcher.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/KeyCatcher.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/hanfei/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KeyCatcher-hijnrqhwiafuxtdjmdubtsijyhwh/Build/Intermediates/KeyCatcher.build/Debug/KeyCatcher.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/KeyCatcher_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/hanfei/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KeyCatcher-hijnrqhwiafuxtdjmdubtsijyhwh/Build/Products/Debug/KeyCatcher

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAlert", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I choose the template for new project, I select `command line tool` instead of `CoCoa Application` as I just need CoCoa to display an alertbox. Does anyone have ideas about this..

Answer (score 1):

That's because NSAlert is not `#imported`.

[AppKit.h](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/ObjC_classic/Intro/IntroAppKit.html) is not included by default when you create a **command line tool** , as you can see in the link, AppKit imports `NSAlert.h`.

EDIT:
First, to compile you need to add the **Cocoa** framework in your project.

Second, all the code should be enclosed in the `@autoreleasepool` section

```
@autoreleasepool {

    // insert code here...
    NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    [alert setMessageText:@"Hi there."];
    [alert runModal];    
}
```

Your code will compile and run, but I think you'll have some other runtime errors.

Comment: Yes.. "symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64". Create a new `command line tool` project in Xcode 5.0.2 and paste the codes into `main.m` reproduces the problem..

Comment: It seems that it can't find the dynamic library although the header files are included.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error in C++ project that was using a NSAlert, this worked for me:

1) Adding

```
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```

2) Adding Cocoa Framework in project->Buld Phases->Link Binary With Libraries.

3) Setting "Type" of all my .cpp files to "Objective-C++ Source" in the most right column in xCode.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this before main function

```
    #import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import AppKit as mentioned by others and – as important as the framework – you need a run loop. So insert before the `runModal` line

```
[NSApplication sharedApplication];
```

to launch the "application" and the run loop